# I'm trying to make a function in JS to search the <td> tags in an HTML table but it doesn't work if I use any <th></th> tags in it

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

EDIT: Nevermind, I just fixed my problem by making the header a separate table to hold all of my  tags

So I have a HTML table and I want to have a search bar to search the table because it's pretty large. I tried copying the code from this W3 schools tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) and I got it modified and working for the table, but only if I don't use any rows that include  tags.

Here's my currently working code (I commented out the code segment that was giving me trouble):

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    
    <table id="myUL" class="BuyBooksTable">
        <!--<tr>
            <th colspan="3">Books</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Purchase Item</th>
        </tr> -->
        <div id="myULSmaller">
        <tr>
            <td>Alice</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Carol</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        </div>
    </table>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
            // Declare variables
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById('myInput');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're searching on `getElementsByTagName("tr")`. Have you tried changing that to also search for `<th>` tags?

Comment: Note `<div>` is invalid child of `<table>`. Use a `<tbody>` instead

Answer (score 2):

Using `querySelectorAll`.

Also, you can use `<tbody>` rather than to have a `div` inside your `table`.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  let searchTerm = e.value.toLocaleLowerCase();

  var trs = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
  [].forEach.call(trs, function(tr) { // all trs
    [].forEach.call(tr.children, function(td) { // all tds
      if (td.getAttribute('search')) { // check if the td needs to be considers for search criteria
        if (td.innerText.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
          tr.style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    });
  });

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myUL" class="BuyBooksTable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Books</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Purchase Item</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td search="true">Alice</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td search="true">Bob</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td search="true">Carol</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the value `a` in the line `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` exists. Try this:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    
    <table id="myUL" class="BuyBooksTable">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Books</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Purchase Item</th>
        </tr>
        <div id="myULSmaller">
        <tr>
            <td>Alice</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Carol</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Purchase Item</td>
        </tr>
        </div>
    </table>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
            // Declare variables
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById('myInput');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            //If a doesn't exist, carry on looping:
            if (!a) {
              continue;
            }
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use **:nth-child**(n+3) selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myUL tr:nth-child(n+3)')
```

or edit your code like

```
...
//ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
ul = document.getElementById("myULSmaller");
...
```

or use this

```
let trs = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL tr:nth-child(n+3)');
function myFunction() {
    let filter = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    let emptyStr = filter.length == 0;


    trs.forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = emptyStr || el.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(filter)?"":"none";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nidhins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57422067/4665) answer is great but if you need to search all columns you need to modify it.

I include a variable to track if any cell in the row matches. Highlite that cell and display the row

```js
//Set event listener
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("keyup",function(){
  var normalisedSearch = this.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  //Grab the search tr in the table body
  var searchTrs = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL>tbody>tr");  
  //iterate the cells in the tr
  [].forEach.call(searchTrs,function(tr){
    var visible = false;
    //iterate the cells in the row
    var searchTds = tr.querySelectorAll("td");
    [].forEach.call(searchTds, function(td){
      if(td.innerText.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(normalisedSearch)){
        visible = true;        
        td.style.backgroundColor = normalisedSearch !== "" ? "#CCC" : "";
      }else{
       td.style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
    });    
    //Sit vidibility of the row
    tr.style.display = visible ? "" : "none";    
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myUL" class="BuyBooksTable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Books</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Purchase Item</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alice</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carol</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Purchase Item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```